# iPhone - UILocalNotification fireDate problem

Tags: iphone, date, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to get the fireDate from an already set notification

Heres my code:

```
 NSArray *notificationArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications], nil];



if ([notificationArray count] > 0) {

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    UILocalNotification *locNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    locNotification = [notificationArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSDate *otherDate = locNotification.fireDate; 
 }
```

The locNotification has the values but the last line when I try to instantiate otherDate I'm getting

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM fireDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e4e20'
```

*** Call stack at first throw:

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong init method. Instead of `NSArray`'s `-initWithObjects:`, you want:

```
NSArray *notificationArray = [[ NSArray alloc ] initWithArray:
                                    [[ UIApplication sharedApplication ]
                                       scheduledLocalNotifications ]];
```

You get the exception because `notificationArray` only contains one object, the array returned by `-scheduledLocalNotifications`.

Comment: That was it. Strange that I was getting a result inside my wrong initialized array. Sorry. Newbie problem =) Thank you very much